# How to get Magento 2 base URL?

Tags: url, magento2, base-url

In Magento 1 `Mage::getBaseUrl();`, but in Magento 2 I have to pass responsible class object type in constructor.

I don’t have the idea which class I have to pass?

Answer (score 137, accepted):

In magento 2.

If you want to get Base url ,then you can try below code:

> ```
> /**
> * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $this->_storeManager
> */
>
> $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
> ```

Where `$this->_storeManager` instance of `\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface`

**this above code will give you result**

> http://www.example.com (**If Seo rewrite is enable**)
>
> And  http://www.example.com/index.php (***If Seo rewrite is not
>   enable***)

***If you want Base URL without `index.php`***

> `$this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_WEB)`

**See in details at [`magento2 get base url and media url and static url`](http://www.amitbera.com/magento2-get-base-url-and-media-url-and-static-url/)**

***Using Object Manager***

**Base Url:**

> ```
> $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
> $storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
> $storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
> ```

**Base Url without index.php**

> ```
> $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
> $storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
> $storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_WEB);
> ```

***For getting media  base url:***

> `$this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);`

***for getting link url:***

> ```
> $this->_storeManager->getStore()
>            ->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_LINK);
> ```

### Edit

For getting the  `$this->_storeManager`  You should call  inject `\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager`

at  ***`__construct( )`*** function at **block class**

***just like :***

> ```
> public $_storeManager;
>   public function __construct(
>       \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
>        .....
>     ) {
>        ...
>   $this->_storeManager=$storeManager;
>     }
> ```

### Updated:

Also,you can get **base url** ***directly*** at `phtml` using direct call of `object Manager`.

> ```
> $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
> $storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
> $storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_WEB);
> ```

**Note:** `Directly call of object manager is not good idea`. If you want base url at phtml then inject `StoreManagerInterface` at block

Comment: I would highly discourage the use of the objectmanager directly, like mentioned in this answer. You should do this by injecting the StoreManager into your Block class, like also mentioned in this answer.

Comment: @7ochem, it is depends on developer call :)

Comment: True, I still would highly discourage developers to do so

Comment: @7ochem It's not recommended to use as per Magento, but good to know it exists and how to use it.

Answer (score 63):

Simply use this command if you are using a class that extends `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template`.

```
$this->getBaseUrl()
```

If not, you can use this:

```
$this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl()
```

Or if you are using it in a PHTML template use:

```
$block->getBaseUrl()
```

Comment: Short and efficient

Comment: Nice, thanks you. Do you know if this needs escaping or not? Magento don't seem to have verified it yet.

Comment: @Ben-Space48 Do not need scape, such as Magento 1.

Comment: This answer could really use some more context. You're assuming that they are within a class that extends `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template`. However the OP's question makes no reference to where he is currently coding from. Such as Model, Helper, Controller, etc.

Comment: In a phtml template you should use $block->getBaseUrl() instead of $this->getBaseUrl()

Comment: https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/get-base-url-and-current-url-magento-2/ check link

Answer (score 15):

In Magneto2: This is way to get Url link in PHTML file:

`echo $this->getUrl('about-us')`

I hope it will work for you

Comment: This is not the Base URL

Answer (score 7):

**inject store manager and simply get base url**

```
public $_storeManager;
  public function __construct(
      \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
       .....
    ) {
       ...
  $this->_storeManager=$storeManager;
    }


$this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
```

Note: don't create object manager always inject

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to get a URL from your Magento install's root directory you can just use getUrl. It inherits from the AbstractBlock class (Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock) so you are able to use it an any of your blocks. Here is an example

```
$this->getUrl('pub/media/video/', ['_secure' => $this->getRequest()->isSecure()]).$fileName
```

The first parameter is the path you want, and the second sets the _secure option if the user is browsing over https. You can add to the path by concatenating a specific filename onto the getUrl call or you could add it to the first parameter. The path is relative to the root directory of your Magento install.

Comment: why $this->getUrl('pub/media/catalog/product') this give me path upto catalog directory and ignoring product directory?

Answer (score 2):

Well if it's Magento 2.0.0. CE Stable version and any "Context" type of object is loaded already in Block class like `Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context` then just call `getStoreManager()->getStore()->getBaseUrl()` function like below:

```
$context->getStoreManager()->getStore()->getBaseUrl()
```

inside the constructor also you can pass arguments like `\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA` inside this `getBaseUrl()` function.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Simply: `<?php $block->getBaseUrl() ?>`

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to get media in PHTML is:

```
$block->getViewFileUrl('images/myimage.png');
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the base URL with a path, use the `\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface` and add `\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_WEB` as a parameter:

```
<?php

class Sample
{
    public function __construct(
        private readonly \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlBuilder
    ) {}

    public function getUrl() {
        return $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                'some/path/here',
                [
                   '_secure' => true, // optional
                   '_type' => \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_WEB
                ]
            );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your block class file add following function:

```
public function getImageUrl($link_url = '')
    {
        if(!empty($link_url))
        {
            $media_url = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);

            return $media_url.'/'.$link_url;
        }
        else
        {
            return '#';
        }
    }
```

And call this from your .phtml template file with following:

```
$block->getImageUrl('<relative image path>')
```

Answer (score -1):

In your magento root create Test.php file.

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
include('app/bootstrap.php');
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface'); 
$baseUrl= $storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get Magento2 Base url by using this:

```
$this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl()
```

Answer (score -2):

In magento 2.

**If you want to get Base url ,then you can use the below code:**

```
$this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl()
```

**By using objectManager ,you can use the following code**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$storeManager = $objectManager>get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');

$storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
```