# How to add link to homepage in top menu? (Magento 2)

Tags: magento2, menu, toplinks, topmenu, luma-theme

How do you add a link to the homepage in the top menu? It must be the first link, after this link must be the links to the categories.

Thanks in advance.

<sub>Extra information: my theme is based on the build-in Luma theme, I'm using Magento 2.1.</sub>

Comment: I don't know which 'url' I should use to make it link to the homepage, such that it works on all stores in a multi-store configuration.

Comment: Try to find answer here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/84980/how-to-get-magento2-base-url

Comment: See linked duplicate. The URL would be `$this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl()` with an instance of `Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface` in `$this->storeManager`