# How to get the Magento 2 SITE URL inside a module?

Tags: magento2, module

I want to send POST request from my magento 2 module to a Rest API with details like site URL.
Example: if my site is http://thisisademostore.com.
I should get this value inside my module.

Comment: Try this - $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl() and refer this - http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/84980/how-to-get-magento2-base-url

Comment: you can use the same method like Magento 1 - $this->getUrl();