# How to pass store code to custom URL in magento 2

Tags: module, url, helper, magento2.3.0

I would like to add store code to a custom URL in Magento 2.3.0

Actually, I want to pass store code to a custom URL in my custom module based on relevant store order.

Let's take an example:

```
public function getCustomUrl($orderData) {        
    if($this->emailHelper->dynamicUrl()){
        return $this->urlInterface->getUrl($this->emailHelper->dynamicUrl()).'oId/'.$orderData->getIncrementId().'/fId/'.$this->getFollowUpId();
    }else {
        return $this->urlInterface->getUrl('route/controller/index/'.'oId/'.$orderData->getIncrementId().'/fId/'.$this->getFollowUpId());
    }
}
```

In the above code

- **$orderData** = order object i can get storeId in this object
- **$this->emailHelper->dynamicUrl()** = get custom string from system config
- **$orderData->getIncrementId()** = pass orderId to url params
- **$this->getFollowUpId()** = module custom table ID pass to url params.

Above code, the result is `http://example.com/default/seo/oId/000000112/fId/179` where `/default/` is store code. I would like to pass `/store2Code/ instead of`/default/`where`/store2Code/` is order placed on store 2.

So in short pass store code based on the placed order store.

**Note :** I have enabled pass store code to URL from system config. so the reason for this store code is showing in URL.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can try like this `$this->storeManager->getStore()->getStoreUrl().'/'.$this->storeManager->getStore()->getCode().'oId/'.$orderData->getIncrementId().'/fId/'.$this->getFollowUpId();`

Comment: It is working fine when you use this in frontend but when you use for backend operation like cron or admin area it is not working.

Comment: haven't tried it before but maybe setting the current store first using `setCurrentStore($storeId);` will make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use store emulation `(Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation)` to set store for backend operation and Try below code.

```
return $this->storeManagerInterface->getStore()->getBaseUrl().$this->emailHelper->dynamicUrl().'/oId/'.$orderData->getIncrementId().'/fId/'.$this->getFollowUpId();
```

It should work.

Comment: Try this but it will return without store code like this `http://example.com/oId/2000000058/fId/192`

Answer (score 1):

I guess this can help you https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/84982/45214 .

In the above link, the BaseUrl is already obtained from storemanager and it will return the store's baseurl. If you have enabled the configuration from the backend to display store_code (for ex. en_US) along with the BaseUrl in the URL, then it will return the BaseUrl/store_code/ as Base Url.

Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: I have already seen this reference url but it's not relevant what i want.