# Admin URL Reset throws a 404 Error

Tags: magento2, admin

I've looked through previous strings where other community members have changed their admin URL in the Magento admin panel.

After the change they get 404 error for the new URL path.

I've changed the env.php file:

```
return [
    'backend' => [
        'frontName' => 'magento'
    ],
```

Then I ran:

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Any advice would really help, I still can't access my dev site.

Thanks so much all.

Comment: Have u tried with `magentoInstanceURl/magento`?

Comment: I'm not certain I'm entirely following, like have I tried: www.storename.ca/magento ~ yes, I have

Comment: I think I see what you're getting at. I'm just reading this string. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/84980/how-to-get-magento-2-base-url/84982#84982