# How to get absolute path from category in megamenu?

Tags: magento2, php, url, megamenu

i'm using the MageDelight Megamenu extension for a website with different stores in different countries, ex:

> mystore.com/en_uk/

> mystore.com/en_us/

While creating the menu in admin i put the relative path in each category's URL box (see screenshot) instead of the absolute path so that i don't have to create a menu instance for each country :
[image]

Now if i click on a category in the menu i will be sent to the correct page based on the country i'm in, ex:

> mystore.com/en_uk/about-us.html

But there's a problem: i have a category called 'New Season' which contains subcategories.
If i click on one of them ,let's say Woman i get sent CORRECTLY to the woman subcategory of new season and the url will look like this:

> mystore.com/en_uk/new-season/woman.html

The problem is that, since i added a relative path, from here if i click on another category (ex: About Us) i will be sent to a 404 page because the link will look like this:

> mystore.com/en_uk/new-season/woman/about-us.html

instead of just:

> mystore.com/en_uk/about-us.html

How can i fix it without having to create a menu for each country with absolute paths?

Here's the relevant block of code:

```
<?php
    $megaMenuLink = $item->getItemLink() ? : '#';
?>    
    <a href="<?= /* @noEscape */ $megaMenuLink ?>" <?= $open_in_newtab_text ?>>
            <span class="megaitemicons"><?= /* @noEscape */ $item->getItemFontIcon() ?></span>
            <?= /* @noEscape */ __($megaMenuName) ?>
        </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `getBaseUrl()` method and concatenate the `$megaMenuLink` to it.

Refer to this answer for more information on the method: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/84982/101146